# Update value of the last entry of a database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a table with

```
CREATE TABLE bereitsgespielt (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                             dateiname TEXT, startzeit NUMERIC,
                              endzeit NUMERIC);
```

I entered

```
1 Hallo 3 4
2 Hallo 5 6
```

I want to update `endzeit` of the last entry, ie with the highest `id`.

I tried

```
UPDATE `bereitsgespielt` SET endzeit = 5 
WHERE dateiname = 'Hallo' ORDER DESC LIMIT 1;

UPDATE bereitsgespielt SET endzeit = 5 
WHERE dateiname = 'Hallo' ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Both crashed `SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1`.

```
UPDATE bereitsgespielt SET endzeit='5' WHERE rowid=2;
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify column in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
UPDATE bereitsgespielt
SET endzeit = 5
WHERE dateiname = 'Hallo' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

[image]
<sup>Image source: https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html</sup>

Comment: This works only when a non-standard [compile option](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit) is enabled, i.e., not on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look up the last ID with a subquery:

```
UPDATE bereitsgespielt
SET endzeit = 5
WHERE dateiname = 'Hallo'
  AND id = (SELECT max(id)
            FROM bereitsgespielt
            WHERE dateiname = 'Hallo');     -- same filter here
```